# Combined image change and movement animation doesn't play properly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

Having simple code like below, the animation of changing the image and movement is not displayed properly. The image is not moving together with the whole view, but fades out and then fades in in the destination spot. Please see the image.

```
struct AnimationTestView: View {
    @State var selected: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if !selected {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            
            Image(systemName: selected ? "plus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        selected.toggle()
                    }
                }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit: Found a solution, inspired by Benzy Neez's answer. What makes it working is simply adding `.drawingGroup()` modifier to the second image.

Comment: Unclear what the desired behavior is, but it's changing positions because you're adding/removing a view from the stack by doing `if !selected`. That causes the position change

Comment: The desired behavior is that the image content is moving together with its background, not fade out in initial position and then fade in in the destination point.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the name of the image, this actually replaces the image, so a transition happens. This is why you are seeing one image fade out and the other fade in.

The way to avoid this is to show the filled image in an overlay. The image is always there, but you change its opacity according to the selection. You said in a comment that you wanted the transition to happen at the destination point, so you can add a delay to the opacity change to achieve this. However, in order that the two images slide over to the other position together, the overlay and the base need to be combined by applying `.drawingGroup`. Like this:

```swift
HStack {
    if !selected {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .overlay {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .background(.yellow)
                .opacity(selected ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.easeInOut.delay(selected ? 0.2 : 0), value: selected)
        }
        .drawingGroup()
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                selected.toggle()
            }
        }
    Spacer()
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Indeed, it does work, thank you. A bit overcomplicated for such a simple use case but it looks to me that it's a bug, because the original code works just fine on iOS 17, but not on 16.4

Comment: When I tried the original code on an iPhone 14 simulator running iOS 17.0 it looks very much like your gif. The unfilled circle just fades out, it doesn't move over, and the filled circle is fading in from the moment you tap. If you want the fade in to happen after the empty circle and/or yellow background reaches the destination then I would be surprised to see it working without some explicit delay somewhere. BTW, if the answer helped, you are welcome to upvote or accept it ;)

Comment: Actually, there is easy fix for my original code. It's enough to add .drawingGroup() modifier for the second image and it works fine.

Comment: @Wujo It's not quite what you said you wanted, because the image starts changing from the moment you tap, as opposed to fading in when the yellow background reaches the destination. By the time the yellow background has finished moving, the filled image is fully showing. But if that's what you really want then problem solved. I wonder if the answer helped anyway?